# Integrating AirPlay with default Android media player to stream protected movie

Tags: android, media-player, drm, airplay

I have developed an Android application which playbacks WideVine protected movies using default Android MediaPlayer. Now there is a requirement to integrate AirPlay into the application so that user can watch videos on AppleTV. I have searched a lot but seems like streaming protected movies through airplay isn't straight forward business. I will be very grateful if someone could point me to the right direction.

Farooq-